# Define Extension function on GETx

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am trying to define an `extension` function on `GetInterface` as

```
extension FindOrPut on GetInterface {
  S findOrPut<S>(S dependency,{String? tag}){
    if(GetInstance().isRegistered<S>(tag: tag)){
      return GetInstance().find<S>(tag: tag);
    }
    return GetInstance().put<S>(dependency,tag: tag);
  }
}
```

Which is same as the `extension Inst on GetInterface` developed by the [GETx](https://pub.dev/packages/get) team. But my code is not working as expected.

**Note:** If I put the extension function code in the same file where it will be used; It works fine. But if I put the above code in the separate file function not found on Get.

Comment: You need to import manually that file where you want to use

Comment: haha I think I need a break :-p

Answer (score 5):

I created the FindOrPut extension on GetInterface. Please check the below code it is working fine.

```
import 'package:amigo/src/controllers/test_controller.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

extension FindOrPut on GetInterface {
  S findOrPut<S>(
    S dependency, {
    String? tag,
    bool permanent = false,
    InstanceBuilderCallback<S>? builder,
  }) {
    if (GetInstance().isRegistered<S>(tag: tag)) {
      return GetInstance().find<S>(tag: tag);
    }
    return GetInstance().put<S>(dependency, tag: tag, permanent: permanent);
  }
}

class ExtensionTesting extends StatelessWidget {
  ExtensionTesting({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  //TODO: Include your getx controller here with findOrPut function
  final TestController _testController = Get.findOrPut(TestController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white30,
      child: Obx(() => Text(_testController.name.value)),
    );
  }
}
```

For working code please check the [extension_method_implementation](https://github.com/Mr-Bhardwa7/extension_method_implementation) repo.

Comment: Thanks Animesh. I am sorry I have forgot to mention the scope problem. Please check my edit.

Comment: @FaiiziiAwan, Please check the git repo I updated the code and now it's working with separated file too.